# How to create branches on top of exiting branches in git?

Tags: git, branch

the title says everything. I want to create a branch on top of an existing branch. I tried to do it with switching to a new branch and creating a new branch while still having the branch checked out. But the Bitbucket.org-Page shows that I made something wrong, it just created new branches ahead of the master branch..

Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you meant to create branch from another branch. If so, take a look at [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

In your case it will be like this:

```
git checkout -b newbranch oldbranch
```